# Capturing http headers in Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to capture a token that I set in the http header inside my Angular application.

This is how I am serving my Angular application :

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var router = express.Router();
var utils = require('./utils);

console.log('——————————- Run on port '+ port);

/****************************** Router ***************************/
router.get('*', function(req, res){
    token = utils.generateToken(); 
    res.set('X-Auth', token).sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/public/app' });
});
```

This token that I am setting in the header is what I would like to capture inside my Angular application. I am kind of lost on where and how to do that ? I am using Angular 9. Any hints where to start ?

Answer (score 1):

the http clent return JSON data if you want to read all respond body you need to set observe option to `response`now the result will be of type `HttpResponse`
you can now read all respond header ,type, status

```js
http
  .get<any>('url', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe((res : HttpResponse) => {
    console.log(rep.headers.get('X-Token'));
    localStorage.setItem('token',res.headers.get('X-Token'))
  });
```

check this  [http reading the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the headers from the Response Class like below:

```
http.get('/controller/action')
    .subscribe((response:Response) => {
       console.log(response.headers);
     });
```

Comment: this will work in old verion but now ,http return response.json() by default.